# showing the number of times dice rolled

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, javascript-objects

I am trying to create a program that will give me the number of times the dice landed on a number after rolling 1000 times. It is returning the result of every roll to me and I only want it to return the last one. Thoughts?

```
var dice1 = {}; 
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var dieValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    var randomRoll = Math.ceil(Math.random()* this.dieValue.length);

    if(randomRoll in dice1) {
        dice1[randomRoll]++;
    }
    else {
        dice1[randomRoll] = 1;
    }

    console.log(dice1);

}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x38pL8q8/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to log the last roll, put the log statement outside the for loop:

```
var dice1 = {}; 
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var dieValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    var randomRoll = Math.ceil(Math.random()* this.dieValue.length);

    if(randomRoll in dice1) {
        dice1[randomRoll]++;
    }
    else {
        dice1[randomRoll] = 1;
    }
}

console.log(dice1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `this` as you are not referring a property in the `this` context but using a variable. Also note, you should `log` it out of the loop

```js
var dice1 = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  var dieValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  var randomRoll = Math.ceil(Math.random() * dieValue.length);
  if (randomRoll in dice1) {
    dice1[randomRoll] ++;
  } else {
    dice1[randomRoll] = 1;
  }
}
console.log(dice1);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does `var dice1 = {}` set `this.dice1` to `{}` ? e.g.; `var abc = 123; console.log(this.abc)`

Comment: `console.log(this.abc)` will be `undefined` right ?

Comment: Try `var abc = 123; console.log(this.abc)` at `console`

Comment: @guest271314, `function test() {
  var a = 10;
  console.log(this.a);
}
test();`

Comment: At chromium , `test()` returns `undefined` ; though `var a = 10; console.log(this.a)` logs `10` to `console`

Comment: @guest271314, In global context, this refers to `window` in browser and `var a` is `key` of the window..That is why it is not `undefined`.. Correct me if it is not convincing..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106533/discussion-between-guest271314-and-rayon-dabre).